# Any way to remove symbols from a lemmatize word set using python

Tags: python, nlp

I got a lemmatize output from the below code with a output words consisting of " : , ? , !, ( )" symbols

`output_H3 = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower(), pos=wordnet.VERB) for w in processed_H3_tag]`

output :-

- ['**hide()**', '**show()**', '**methods:**', 'jquery', 'slide', '**elements:**',
  'launchedw3schools', '**today!**']

Expected output :-

- ['**hide**', '**show**', '**methods**', 'jquery', 'slide', '**elements**',
  'launchedw3schools', '**today**']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `translate()` and `string.punctuation` (``` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_``{|}~ ```):

```
trans = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)   
output_wo_punc = [s.translate(trans) for s in output]
```

Which returns:

```
> ['hide', 'show', 'methods', 'jquery', 'slide', 'elements', 'launchedw3schools', 'today']
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions can help:

```
import re 

output = [
    "hide()",
    "show()",
    "methods:",
    "jquery",
    "slide",
    "elements:",
    "launchedw3schools",
    "today!",
]


>>> import pprint
>>> expected = [re.sub(r'[:,?!()]', '', e) for e in output]
>>> pprint.pprint(expected)
['hide',
 'show',
 'methods',
 'jquery',
 'slide',
 'elements',
 'launchedw3schools',
 'today']
```

This replaces anything in your list of non desired characters with nothing.